# Pinter 10.E.5: Let $a$ and $b$ commute. Prove: There is an element $c$ in $G$ whose order is $lcm(m,n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is 10.E.5 from Pinter.

> Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group $G$.
>
> Let $\text{ord}(a) = m$ and $\text{ord}(b) = n$.
>
> Let $a$ and $b$ commute.
>
> Prove:
>
> There is an element $c$ in $G$ whose order is $lcm(m,n)$.
>
> (HINT: Use 10.E.4 together with 10.D.3. Let $c = a^i b$ where $a^i$ is a certain power of $a$.

Here is 10.E.4:

> Let $a$ and $b$ commute.
>
> If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $ord(ab) = mn$.
>
> (HINT: Use 10.E.2)

Here is 10.D.3:

> If $ord(a) = km$, then $ord(a^k) = m$.

Here's the start of one approach.

As Pinter suggests, let

$$c = a^i b$$

Let's start from what is to be proven:

$$ord(c) = lcm(m,n)$$

$$ord(a^i b) = lcm(m,n)$$

$$(a^i b)^{lcm(m,n)} = e$$

$$(a^i)^{lcm(m,n)} b^{lcm(m,n)} = e$$

$$a^{i lcm(m,n)} b^{lcm(m,n)} = e$$

$$a^{i lcm(m,n)} = b^{-lcm(m,n)}$$

$$a^i a^{lcm(m,n)} = b^{-lcm(m,n)}$$

$$a^i = b^{-lcm(m,n)} a^{-lcm(m,n)}$$

$$a^i = (ba)^{-lcm(m,n)}$$

In other words, we're aiming to solve for $a^i$.

However, this doesn't seem too helpful as it simplifies to $e$.

Moreover, we haven't used 10.E.5 or 10.D.3.

---

It seems that this part of the hint:

> $c = a^i b$ where $a^i$ is a certain power of $a$

is suggesting that we find an $a^i$ such that $gcd(a^i,b) = 1$.

And once that's done, apply 10.E.4:

$$ ord(a^i b) = ord(a^i) n $$

And hopefully, together with 10.D.3, change that to:

$$ ord(a^i b) = lcm(m,n)$$

---

This question has been discussed in a few places on math.se.

Here's [one approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78544/if-orda-m-ordb-n-then-does-there-exist-c-such-that-ord-c-lcmm-n).

The first part of the answer appears to prove 10.E.4 and solves the case for when $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

The second part of the answer does not appear to apply 10.D.3 as recommended by Pinter.

---

There are many approaches illustrated on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10616/order-of-elements-is-lcm-closed-in-abelian-groups).

However, none appear to use the path suggested by Pinter.

---

The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555601/problem-5-from-section-e-of-chapter-10-of-pinters-book-of-abstract-algebra) essentially restates part of Pinter's hint.

---

Is there a clear approach which uses Pinter's suggestions to use 10.D.3, 10.E.4, and only what has been covered up to that point in the book?

---

## Bill's answer converted to Pinter's notation

- This is a conversion of the proof in Bill's answer to the notation in Pinter.
- It also makes many of the implied steps explicit.
- This will hopefully make the proof more familiar and digestible to folks coming to Pinter's book and abstract algebra perhaps for the first time.

We induct on

$$ ord(a) ord(b) $$

### Part 1

If

$$ ord(a) ord(b) = 1 $$

the only possible values are:

$$    ord(a) = 1 $$

$$    ord(b) = 1 $$

so

$$    lcm(ord(a),ord(b)) = 1 $$

$$    ord(c) = 1 $$

which means

$$    c^1 = e $$

thus

$$    c = e $$

### Part 2

Now let's consider the case where

$$ ord(a)ord(b) != 1$$

Split off $p^k$ in $ord(a)$, $ord(b)$. I.e.

$$ ord(a) = xP  $$
$$ ord(b) = yP' $$

where

$$    P'|P $$

$$  P = p^k > 1 \tag{7} $$

$p$ is prime and $p∤x,y$.

Then, by 10.D.3:

$$ ord(a^P) = x  \tag{1} $$
$$ ord(b^{P'}) = y \tag{2} $$

$$ ord(a^x) = P  \tag{3} $$
$$ ord(b^y) = P' \tag{4} $$

By induction, there is a $c$ with

$$ ord(c) = lcm(x,y) $$

Substitute (1) and (2):

$$ ord(c) = lcm(ord(a^P),ord(b^{P'})) \tag{5} $$

$$ c = a^P b^{P'} \tag{6} $$

Substitute (6):

$$ ord(a^P b^{P'}) = lcm(ord(a^P),ord(b^{P'})) $$

So:

$$    ord(a^x c) $$

$$    lcm(ord(a^x),ord(c)) $$

Substitute (3) and (5):

$$    lcm(P, lcm(ord(a^P), ord(a^{P'}))) $$

$$    lcm(P, lcm(x,y)) $$

Since   $P = p^k$   where   $p$ is prime   and   $p$ is coprime to $x$ and $y$:

$$    P lcm(x,y) $$

$$    lcm(xP, yP') $$

$$    lcm(ord(a), ord(b)) $$

Thus:

$$    ord(a^x c) = lcm(ord(a), ord(b))  $$

---

## Pinter's approach

This is a start of an approach that closely follows Pinter's hint.

(I have this written up in a text file and didn't have time to format as LaTeX.)

```
Let ord(a) = m.
Let ord(b) = n.

Let i = gcd(m,n).           (1)

Let ord(a) = k i            (2)
========================================
Consider: ord(a^i b)

If ord(a^i) and ord(b) are relatively prime then by 10.E.4:

ord(a^i b) = ord(a^i) ord(b)        (3)
========================================
By eq (2) and 10.D.3:

ord(a^i) = k                (4)

Eq (2):

ord(a) = k i

Substitute (4):

ord(a) = ord(a^i) i

Solve for ord(a^i):

ord(a^i) = ord(a)/i         (5)
========================================
Eq (3):

ord(a^i b) = ord(a^i) ord(b)

Substitute (5):

ord(a^i b) = ord(a)/i ord(b)

ord(a^i b) = ord(a) ord(b) / i

Substitute (1):

ord(a^i b) = ord(a) ord(b) / gcd(m,n)

ord(a^i b) = ord(a) ord(b) / gcd(ord(a),ord(b))

ord(a^i b) = lcm(a,b)
----------------------------------------
```

The only remaining part left to do is to handle the case where `ord(a^i)` and `ord(b)` are not relatively prime.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304339/let-a-and-b-commute-if-m-and-n-are-relatively-prime-then-ordab).

Comment: Yes, that's the approach used in the proof I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10628/242)  (E.4 is used in the final line)

Comment: @BillDubuque Hey Bill! I'll take a closer look. That post mentions that G is abelian. Whereas 10.E.5 does not require G to be abelian (only that $a$ and $b$ commute). So I thought it might be a slightly different question and approach.

Comment: No they're equivalent - just apply it to the abelian sugroup generated by $a,b$ (or note that my proof only needs that $a,b$ commute).

Comment: @BillDubuque Aha! You **do** use 10.D.3! You first say $ord(X) = AP$. Then you use 10.D.3 when you say: $ord(X^P) = A$. Cool. :-)

Comment: Yes, it is used in a few places without explicit mention. I just added a link to a  proof of E.4 there.

Comment: I added a link for the proof of D.3 too.

Comment: @BillDubuque OK, I converted your proof to the notation that Pinter uses. (I.e. renamed X -> a, Y -> b, Z -> c. I also did A -> x and B -> y, O -> ord). That's made it more familiar to me. :-) I think I understand all the jumps you make in the steps there.

Comment: @BillDubuque Off topic but not sure where else to ask... Are you the same Bill that worked on the Macsyma computer algebra system?

Comment: Glad to see you've got it. Yes, that's me,

Comment: @BillDubuque I wouldn't say yet that I've "got it". But I can see the overall structure now. :-)

Comment: @BillDubuque Fascinating! I've worked on a couple of (very simple) computer algebra libraries. [One for Scheme](https://github.com/dharmatech/mpl) and [another for C#](https://github.com/dharmatech/Symbolism).

Comment: @BillDubuque OK, I added the conversion of your proof to Pinter's notation to my post. I'm fairly sure about most of it except for the part that follows $ord(a^x c)$. If that part wasn't properly translated, feel free to let me know. :-)

Comment: @BillDubuque I've added another start of an approach to the question (labeled "Pinter's Approach"). Not sure if what I have there is valid and if the uncompleted part can be proved. It aims to more directly follow the hint given in the text.

Comment: In the copy of Pinter I'm looking at the hint says "let $c$ be a certain power of $a$" vs. what you wrote above. I don't think either hint works (given what has been presented up to that point), so you may be on a wold goose chase (i.e. the hint may be a (pedagogical) error in the book).

Comment: Update: I found a copy of the 2nd edition and the hint has been corrected to what you wrote. But I still think that it is a pedagogical error since I doubt it can be done easily using that type of $c$ using only what has been presented up to that point (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10631/242) for one way - but that goes beyond what has been presented). So it seems they didn't do a good job of correcting that error in the first edition.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done by exploiting prime factorisations. With your notations, write

$$m= p_1^{k_1}\dots p_s^{k_s}; n = p_1^{l_1}\dots p_s^{l_s}$$

We can express $lcm(m,n)$ as

$$p_1^{\min\{k_1, l_1\}}\dots p_s^{\min\{k_s,l_s\}}$$

If we can find elements $c_i$ with $ord(c_i) = p_i^{\min\{k_i,l_i\}}$, then the element you are looking for is $c=\prod_i c_i$ because the order is multiplicative on commutating elements with coprime orders.

Put $$c_i =\begin{cases} a^{m/p^{k_i}} \quad k_i\leq l_i \\ b^{n/p^{l_i}} \quad l_i < k_i \end{cases}$$

and you see we are done.

Comment: That's essentially the same as the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10628/242) I linked in the comments, except I do the induction *explicitly* (vs. implicitly above).

Comment: In general, if you have a set of group elements whose orders are pairwise relatively prime, is the order of the product of the elements equal to the product of their individual orders? Let $G$ be a group and $A\subseteq G$. If $A = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ and $gcd(ord(a_i),ord(a_j))=1$ for each $i\neq j$, then $ord(a_1a_2...a_n) = ord(a_1)ord(a_2)...ord(a_n)$.